# System.IO.FileStream creates duplicate folders in Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

I'm creating some binary files using FileStream and BinaryWriter, and placing the file in MyDocuments. But the thing is, when I leave an Explorer window open, I'm seeing duplicate Document folders.

> Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in Windows?

If I close and reopen explorer, the extra document folders disappear. Not a big deal, but it makes for a nasty client experience.

**Code**

```
var fileName = "FileStreamTest_{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.bin";
var filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string file = Path.Combine(filePath, string.Format(fileName, DateTime.Now));
short length = 5;

using (var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
    {
        writer.Write(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            writer.Write((float)i);
        }
    }
}
```

**Explorer**

[image: Duplicating Documents]

**Addendum**

I should clarify. This doesn't actually duplicate the folder C:\users\*username*\Documents. The duplication is with the links show to that Documents folder in the Windows Explorer Navigation Pane.

- Environment: Windows 10 Education
- .NET version: 4.6.1

Comment: Im not getting this when I run your code :P

Comment: Why you calling `writer.Write()` twice? moreover, those files are not created by your posted code

Comment: @Rahul the first write writes the number of elements, the second puts them in..

Comment: Make sure you are displaying the file extensions in window explorer.  You can't have duplicates with same file name so the extensions must be different.

Comment: @BugFinder - Really? I'm running Window10 Edu targeting .NET 4.6.1. For testing, I just stuffed this code into a Console application project. Explorer has to be already open when running the code. Then you'll see it. If you open Explorer after running the code, it won't be there. In fact, it appears that all you need to do is close Explorer and reopen and it'll fix itself.

Comment: I am not seeing this behavior, either.  Prior to running the application I opened the Documents directory in File Explorer.  I am running Windows 10 Pro v1511 and targeting .NET v4.6.1.

Comment: I did what you did.. Im not seeing the duplication

Comment: Ok. Well, thanks for testing. That concludes that this problem must be environmental. Not sure what I should do about this post. It's not resolved, but given the repro is only on my machine, there's no way to track down the problem.

Comment: From [some quick Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%2010%20this%20pc%20multiple%20documents) it appears this is a common problem, possibly related to OneDrive.  Judging by the green check mark on the icon in your screenshot, it looks like you're using OneDrive?  I do not, so perhaps that's why I'm not seeing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is caused by your code.  Have you defined a non-standard location for your Documents folder in Win 10, by any chance?  If so, that may be a contributing factor.  I've been Googling like mad for the past few weeks to find a fix without any luck.

On my machine, any write operation to a file within the Documents folder triggers the issue - even copying a file.  As I type this, I have 19 duplicate "Documents" links under "This PC."  Harmless (seemingly), but maddening.

Update: Here's a fix / workaround.  The navigation bar will be a bit messier, but it's better than the status quo.  In File Explorer, go to View -> Options -> Change folder and search options -> View -> Scroll down to 'Navigation Pane' -> [X] Show all folders